# Scaling down font-size using lang css directive gives weird results

Tags: html, css

I am creating multilingual site and I have realized that some languages such as French are quite wordy which breaks my design which was done using English copy. So I have been trying to use the `:lang` css directive mainly to reduce the font-size across the board for French landing page. But the results are quite counter-intuitive. A percentage reduction by a small amount results in a big reduction in actual size.

Perhaps my understanding is incorrect. Here is an example code that explains this phenomenon

```css
:lang(fr)
{
  font-size:90%;
}
h1 {
  font-size:3em;
}
```

```html
<h1>
This is my heading
</h1>
<h1 lang="fr">
This is my very very long verbose heading in French
</h1>
```

As you can see, my French headline became very small with only 10% reduction in font-size.

Comment: What's wrong here, I think it is working as expected. Your french lang showing 90% by inheriting from your parent tag body. Until we set any font-size for body browsers may set the size 16px (in chrome) and :lang(fr) selector showing 90% of 16px. Keep it mind percentage inherit from parent container not from siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Perhaps my understanding is incorrect." yes I think so. You expecting font size for French will show 90% of 3em which you defined for `h1 { font-size:3em;}`.

But keep your mind when you set something like that `font-size:90%` means font size will inherit 90% from immediate parent where we already set the font size. From your given code you not set the font size for `<h1 lang="fr">` container (in this case it is 'body').

If we not set the font-size for body browser by default set 16px (in chrome but it can vary browser to browser). So pseudo-class `:lang(fr)` selector is higher priority than only tag selector `h1` and it is inheriting from it's container body tag means "14.4px".

My suggestion is to overcome this situation apply the `em` unit. `em` unit inherit from top most parent. See following approach, it may be can give you a way.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
h1 { 
  font-size:3em; /* means 16*3 = 48px; */
}
h1:lang(fr) {
  font-size:2.7em; /* (48*90)/100 = 43.2px/16px = 2.7em */
}
```

```html
<h1>Actual Font Size</h1>
<h1 lang="fr">French Font Size</h1>
```

Comment: I knew I was wrong in my understanding :) Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: While I did understand your explanation, what is the best solution for the issue I am facing with some languages. If you can suggest something, it would be greatly helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wish I could give you more upvote!